# Change System Time/Date

Tags: linux, linux-mint, date, settings, timezone

I'm running Linux Mint 15 with KDE 4.10.4+

Here's what I get when I run *date*:

> user:~ > date
>   Die Okt 29 15:47:54 UTC 2013

Where "Die Okt" indicates a German-language setting, which I don't mind. However, I'm not in the UTC timezone, and I'd like to configure my system time/date to display the correct timezone. I've tried going into System Settings and configuring Date and Time, which is temporarily successful, but after restarting the system, it always resets to UTC.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`.

Or you can use `timedatectl`. List all available timezones with

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

And set it as root user with

```
timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>
```

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata worked like a charm, thanks!